# How can I change the page title?

Tags: 8

In Drupal 7, I could change the page title with `drupal_set_title(t('New page title'))`. When I try it in Drupal 8, I get a *There is no such function* error.

How can I change the page title?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

As reported in [drupal_set_title() and drupal_get_title() were removed](https://www.drupal.org/node/2067859) that function is deprecated in Drupal 8.

For a dynamic title set from a controller, the code the change record suggests is the following one.

```yaml
mymodule.test:
  path: '/mymodule/test'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\mymodule\Controller\Test::getContent'
    _title_callback: '\Drupal\mymodule\Controller\Test::getTitle'
```

The controller code is the following one.

```php
class Test {

  /**
   * Returns a page title.
   */
  public function getTitle() {
    return  'Foo: ' . \Drupal::config()->get('system.site')->get('name');
  }

  /**
   * Returns a page render array.
   */
  public function getContent() {
    $build = array();
    $build['#markup'] = 'Hello Drupal';
    return $build;
  }

}
```

Alternatively, as the same change record suggests, you could use the `#title` property in a render array. This should be generally avoided, since the title for the page when fully rendered could be different from the title in other contexts (like in the breadcrumbs).

```php
class Test {

  /**
   * Renders a page with a title.
   *
   * @return array
   *   A render array as expected by drupal_render()
   */
   public function getContentWithTitle() {
     $build = array();
     $build['#markup'] = 'Hello Drupal';
     $build['#title'] = 'Foo: ' . Drupal::config()->get('system.site')->get('name');
     return $build;
   }

}
```

Comment: Why do you have to append the system.site->name? That is appended as part of the title that goes into html head if you provide a title string without that.

Answer (score 9):

**drupal_set_title() in Drupal 8**

```
$request = \Drupal::request();
if ($route = $request->attributes->get(\Symfony\Cmf\Component\Routing\RouteObjectInterface::ROUTE_OBJECT)) {
  $route->setDefault('_title', 'New Title');
}
```

**drupal_get_title() in Drupal 8**

```
$request = \Drupal::request();
if ($route = $request->attributes->get(\Symfony\Cmf\Component\Routing\RouteObjectInterface::ROUTE_OBJECT)) {
  $title = \Drupal::service('title_resolver')->getTitle($request, $route);
}
```

**Views**

To change the view title, both `<h1>` and `<head><title>`, according to [this](https://www.drupal.org/node/2067859#comment-14675179).
Create a custom module and place the following in the .module file:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_post_render().
 */
function mymodule_views_post_render(Drupal\views\ViewExecutable $view) {
  if ($view->element['#view_id'] == 'id_of_view') {
    if ($view->element['#display_id'] == 'id_of_display') {
      $title = 'test';
      $view->setTitle($title); // Sets h1
      $route = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getCurrentRouteMatch()->getRouteObject();
      $route->setDefault('_title_callback', function() use ($title) {
        return $title; // sets <head><title>
      }); 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: GET title works fine maybe everywhere. I wonder where to SET the title, cause in preprocess page it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Thanks @rpayanm!
The above is what I need - to change title in my controller action without touching markup and w/o using getTitle().
Here is a more short version: `$route = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteObject(); $route->setDefault('_title', 'New Title');`

Comment: Here is also cross-reference to the CR with different examples: https://www.drupal.org/node/2067859

Answer (score 9):

Change the title tag in the head of your HTML document.

```
function mymodule_preprocess_html(&$variables) {

  $variables['head_title']['title'] = $something;
}
```

Change the title that appears in the page content.

```
function mymodule_preprocess_block(&$variables) {

  if ('page_title_block' == $variables['plugin_id']) {
    $variables['content']['#title'] = $something;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

That function was removed from Drupal 8.
Change record:
[drupal_set_title() and drupal_get_title() were removed](https://www.drupal.org/node/2067859).

You could now set the title when defining the routes in `modulename.routing.yml`.
Example of how it could be done, is shown the change record link above.

Answer (score 5):

I found in D8 that if you're wanting to alter the title for an entity view, you can use hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view_alter(). For example, here's how you could change the view of a user entity with a field on the user "field_display_name", rather than the user ID as the title:

```
/**
* Implements hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view_alter().
*/
function mymodule_user_view_alter(array &$build, Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity, \Drupal\Core\Entity\Display\EntityViewDisplayInterface $display) {
  $build['#title'] = $entity->get('field_display_name')->getString();
}
```

Comment: Good and clean approach. Works fine in D8/

Answer (score 4):

I've found another way, which may be simpler if you don't have a controller and want to modify the title throughout your website. You can use it to modify the title based on the current node.

First, remove the  tag in your html.html.twig
Then, hook hook_page_attachments_alter

```
function mytemplate_page_attachments_alter(array &$page) {
    $page['#attached']['html_head'][] = [
        [
          '#tag' => 'title',
          '#value' => "My title"
        ],
        'title'
    ];
}
```

You can get the current node of taxonomy term with

```
$node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
$term = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('taxonomy_term')
```

Answer (score 3):

Getting the page title works fine as written in @rpayanm's answer. But setting it turned out to be quite complicated. Finally found out that [`hook_preprocess_HOOK()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21themes%21bartik%21bartik.theme/function/bartik_preprocess_page_title/8.2.x) could simply be used to preprocess the page title quite easily.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK().
 */
function MYMODULE_preprocess_page_title(&$variables) {

  if ($MYLOGIC === TRUE) {

    $variables['title'] = 'New Title';
  }
}
```

---

And as already mentioned in other answers here you might additionally use `hook_preprocess_html()` to set the HTML head title tag accordingly.

Comment: This seems to work for some routes, but not for e.g. nodes.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Automatic Entity Label](https://www.drupal.org/project/auto_entitylabel), a very well crafted contributed module for setting node titles and the like.

(Note that 'page title' is a more colloquial way of saying 'entity label', where 'page' is a content entity and 'label' encompasses the title and the equivalent for other entities e.g. comment subjects, taxonomy term names.)

While op appears to be asking for guidance on writing custom code, it's not clear from available details that custom code is the best recommendation. For readers without a very specific reason for duplicating a feature available from contributed code, the Drupal community strongly advises (and site owners strongly benefit from) adopting an existing module.

Answer (score 2):

`drupal_set_title()` and `drupal_get_title()` both are removed from drupal 8 but the best part is this there is a separate block for `page_title`. User can hide or add this block on any page/region.

There are 2 solutions for this.

1. Disable `title_block` on particular page and add new custom block with some markup for title. Now place this block just after the `title_block` in drupal block section.
2. By using `hook_preprocess_block()` function in your `custom_theme.theme` file.
   Here is the code example:

   ```
   function custom_themename_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
     if ('page_title_block' == $variables['plugin_id']) {
       $request = \Drupal::request();
       $path = $request->getRequestUri(); // get current path
       if(strpos($path, 'user')) { //check current path is user profile page
         $variables['content']['#title'] = 'My Profile';
       }
     }
   }
   ```

   In my case I have used above 2nd method, which will work only for user profile page.

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this and tried all of the solutions above. The solution that finally worked was:

```
function mymodule_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  $variables['head_title']['title'] = $something;
}
```

but only after I updated my custom module weight:

```
drush php:eval "module_set_weight('mymodule', 10);"
```

Answer (score 0):

i have changed the page_title block for user/uid to a different custom account field name like this :

```
function hook_preprocess_block(&$variables) {  
  $path = \Drupal::request()->getpathInfo();
  $arg = explode('/', $path);
  if (isset($arg[2]) && $arg[2] == 'user' && isset($arg[3])) {
    if (isset($variables['elements']['content']['#type']) && $variables['elements']['content']['#type'] == 'page_title') {
      $account = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load($arg[3]);
      if(isset($account) && isset($account->field_mycustomfield->value)){
        $variables['content']['#title']['#markup']=$account->field_mycustomfield->value;
      }
    }
  }
}
```