# Change the default "Create new account" title on the User registration page

Tags: 8, theming, users

I would like the change the default title (and probably also the meta title) of the User registration page, currently "Create new account".

I tried the Static and Dynamic page title method described [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/181828/how-do-i-set-the-page-title), as well as a couple of other suggestions, but none of them worked...

Anyone?  I added a print screen of the route (registration_link.register), the URL is user/register.

[image: default page title]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add the following two hooks to your theme's `*.theme` file or your module's `*.module` file. The first to alter the title that's displayed in the page title block. The second to alter the meta title.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK().
 */
function MYTHEME/MYMODULE_preprocess_page_title(&$variables) {

  if (\Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName() == 'user.register') {

    $variables['title'] = t('New Title');
  }
}

/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK().
 */
function MYTHEME/MYMODULE_preprocess_html(&$variables) {

  if (\Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName() == 'user.register') {

    $variables['head_title']['title'] = t('New Title');
  }
}
```

Comment: using 'registration_link.register' as route, the above code worked like a charm.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 9 this will be

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK().
 */
function MYTHEME/MYMODULE_preprocess_page_title(&$variables) {

  if (\Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName() == 'registration_link.register') {

    $variables['title'] = t('New Title');
  }
}

/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK().
 */
function MYTHEME/MYMODULE_preprocess_html(&$variables) {

  if (\Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName() == 'registration_link.register') {

    $variables['head_title']['title'] = t('New Title');
  }
}
```