# Modifying Page Title To Be Separate From Browser Title

Tags: 8, forms

I have a module that contains multiple forms, each form in its own file. I need to modify the page title such that it is different from the browser title for several of these pages. The name of the module is member_login. This is what I have so far:

```
function member_login_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  if (\Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName() == 'member_login.login') {
    $variables['content']['#title'] = t("The new HTML title.");
  }
}
```

I add this function to the .module file. Do I need to call it, or does Drupal call it automatically for it to come into effect? Currently, I do not see it into effect.

Comment: Where exactly in what file are you placing that hook? It belongs into a *.module or *.theme file. Then you need an if-request to check for some URL or whatever pattern to apply your logic.

Comment: @leymannx I updated the original post with the updated code that I'm using. It is now placed in the *.module file, however still no success.

Comment: Have you also tried this one: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/232783/15055