# How to generate breadcrumb title for custom routes?

Tags: 8, theming, hooks

I'm using a custom theme for our Drupal 8 based website, for breadcrumbs I'm using the easy breadcrumbs module.

We have a custom module where the nodes are generated in a custom block dynamically.

Below is the current structure in the module.routing.yml file

```
testmodule.res:
  path: '/subject/{node}' 
  defaults: 
    _controller: '\Drupal\testmodule\Controller\resController::res' 
    _title: ''
  requirements: 
    _permission: 'access content'
```

In the path - `/subject/{node}` the node contains a subject name belonging to a group, for instance resources group subject contain - Physics, Math and Chemistry.

The node in the path /random/{node} will contain the subject name

The breadcrumb pattern will be home>>subject>>Math

But I'm unable to find a way to display the subject name as the last breadcrumb. Do let me know what can be done

Comment: You can use a `_title_callback` to generate a dynamic title for a route rather than setting to ''. This is documented in [the top answer to "How do I set the page title?"](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/181831/48114). I think that may resolve your issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I set the page title?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/181828/how-do-i-set-the-page-title)

Comment: @sonfd, the solution is very confusing to me as I'm a beginner into Drupal development, for _title_callback should I include the the php code in the routing file?I need to set page title for each subject name